# Как перевести число из X СС в Y СС?

Tags: c

Не получается перевести число 405 в 33-ричную сс. Выводится 99, а нужно чтоб выводилось c9.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char hash_table[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int number = 405;
    int osn = 33;
    char array[100];
    int n = 0;
    char ch;
    while (number > 0)
    {
        array[n++] = number % osn;
        number /= osn;
    }
        if (number == osn)
            array[n++] = hash_table[number - 1];
        else
            array[n++] = hash_table[number % osn];

        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
            printf("%c", hash_table[i - 1]);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: что у Вас выводится, и что Вы хотите, чтобы выводилось

Comment: выводится `99`, а нужно чтоб выводилось    `c9`

Comment: У Вас написана какая-то ерунда. Вы сначала в элементы массива `array` записываете целые числа, а потом букву (вероятно, ее ASCII код) из `hash_table`.

Comment: вот я не знаю как число представить как символ если оно больше 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый цикл практически верен, я бы написал так:

```
while (number > 0)
{
  array[n++] = number % osn;
  number /= osn;
}
```

В результате у вас получится "перевернутый" массив индексов из строки "0123456789ab...".
Дальше просто:

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
  printf("%c", hash_table[arr[i-1]]);
```

%c - потому, что Вам надо печатать именно символы, а не целые числа.

Целиком:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        const char hash[] = "0123456789abcdefghjijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int arr[100];
        int num = 405, osn = 33;
        int n = 0;
        while (num > 0)
        {
            arr[n++] = num % osn;
            num /= osn;
        }
        int i;
        for (i = n; i > 0; i--)
            printf("%c", hash[arr[i-1]]);
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: тогда получается что мне второй цикл for вообще не нужен?

Comment: @Саня.C А зачем он? Вы-то сами можете объяснить? Нет, если вам нужно как-то сохранить полученный массив, тогда он, наверное, нужен.

Comment: Мне нужно перевести число и вывести его на экран и все

Comment: после всех этих подсказок у меня получился код(его я написал в вопросе) и он выводит `210`  а не  `с9`

Comment: @Саня.C `if` тут явно лишний

Comment: andy, можешь исправить и добавить в ответ работающий код пожалуйста)

Comment: @Саня.C Я там ошибся, уже поправил

Comment: Igor и  andy.37 , спасибо вам )))все получилось

Comment: andy а почему когда я меняю число и систему счсиления у меня выводит какие-то окошки  `4`      я понял значения на эти  long number = 1508439372;
 int osn = 26;

Comment: @Саня.C `4lnmk4n` - мой вывод

Comment: у вас так выводит?

Comment: у меня выводит 4 и пустые окошки